# Website only works when www prefaces the domain

Tags: nginx, flask, web, gunicorn

I've created a website using nginx and gunicorn and I'm using certbot to handle the sercurity. I am able to acces the website using the [www.mysite.net](http://www.mysite.net) but when I enter mysite.net I get a 404 error. I either need it to redirect to one or the other. Preferably from www to non www. Here is my nginx server config.

```
server {
        server_name www.mysite.net;

        location /static {
                alias /home/colin8297/mysite/static;
        }

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
                include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mysite.net/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mysite.net/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = www.mysite.net) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;
        server_name www.mysite.net;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

I've tried to change the above config file but cannot get it to work. Btw I do have the A record in my server set to both www and no www.

Comment: Try server_name www.mysite.net mysite.net;

Comment: This still gives a 404 Not Found nginx/1.22.0 (Ubuntu) - even without comma

Comment: The 404 error comes from the second `server` block in your question. The `if` block is redirecting only `www.mysite.net`. Probably `server { return 301 https://$host$request_uri; }` is all you need.